# Angular2 does not load custom script when I change the view

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I am still learning Angular 2 so I may be doing something wrong over here.

I have a HTML/CSS template and I am trying to make it work with Angular 2. 
I have created an Angular2 project with a few components...

In the `app.component.html` I have my menu

```
<ul class="clearfix">
     <li><a [routerLink]="['/']">Home</a></li>
     <li><a [routerLink]="['/link1']">Link1</a></li>
     <li><a [routerLink]="['/link2']">Link2</a> </li>
</ul>
```

When I click on one item of the menu it changes the view to the component I made - for example when I click Link1 it shows me the view of link1 component (`link1.component.html`)

In `index.html` I have

```
<app-root>Loading...</app-root>
```

and I have loaded all the CSS and JS files, so the problem here when I click on the menu the view change but Angular2 do not load the Javascript that was loaded in index.html it only does that when I put the direct link.

To be more clear if I put the direct link in the browser **localhost:4200/link1** the script gets loaded and I could see the animation or whatever I have that was loaded in the `index.html` and was called in `link1.component.htm`l but if I am at home and click Link 1 in the menu the view change but the animation or alert... doesn't work.

I don't get any error in the console and in `index.html` I am only loading those two scripts:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/site.min.js"></script>
> ```

Comment: are you using angularcli

Answer (score 0):

Load all the external scripts in the index.html file.

In your case, you should include the following tags in the head segment of the index.html file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/site.min.js"></script>
```